# Convert sub-group heading from a CSV into a seperate column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading in CSV files to a dataframe. The CSV files has a group header rows for different tournaments. I want to seperate this subheader row into it's own column. I will use data from this row for analysis later, to see if the results vary by specific tournament regions.  How can I move the sub header into it's own row. I think it will involve iterating over the rows.

So the data looks like this

| date | P1 | P2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA Hamersely M45 | NaN | NaN |
| 22nd Jul 2023,\n04:00 EDT | 1.75 | 56% |
| 22nd Jul 2023,\n05:00 EDT | 1.85 | 76% |
| Canada Valley Y67 | NaN | NaN |
| 22nd Jul 2023,\n19:00 EDT | 2.37 | 26% |
| 22nd Jul 2023,\n20:00 EDT | 1.97 | 86% |
| 22nd Jul 2023,\n22:00 EDT | 1.75 | 96% |

I want to convert this to

| Tournament | date | P1 | P2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA Hamersely M45 | 2023/07/22 | 1.75 | 56% |
| USA Hamersely M45 | 2023/07/22 | 1.85 | 76% |
| Canada Valley Y67 | 2023/07/22 | 2.37 | 26% |
| Canada Valley Y67 | 2023/07/22 | 1.97 | 86% |
| Canada Valley Y67 | 2023/07/22 | 1.75 | 96% |

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
"Date":['USA Hamersely M45','22nd Jul 2023,\n04:00 EDT','22nd Jul 2023,\n05:00 EDT','Canada Valley Y67','22nd Jul 2023,\n04:00 EDT','22nd Jul 2023,\n05:00 EDT','22nd Jul 2023,\n22:00 EDT'],
  "p1": [np.nan, 1.75, 1.85, np.nan,2.37,1.97,1.75],
  "p2": [np.nan, '56%' , '76%', np.nan,'26%','86%','96%']
  
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()```
````

Comment: From where you got row `USA Hamersely M45 2023/07/22 1.52 36%` in 2nd table?

Comment: It was just the idea.  The data in the table does not matter.  I tire of typing.

Comment: Fixed to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = df[["p1", "p2"]].isna().all(axis=1)

df["tmp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[~mask, "Date"].str.split("\n").str[0])
df["tmp"] = df["tmp"].bfill()

df["Date"] = df.loc[mask, "Date"]
df["Date"] = df["Date"].ffill()

df = df.loc[~mask, ["Date", "tmp", "p1", "p2"]].rename(
    columns={"Date": "Tournament", "tmp": "date"}
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Tournament       date    p1   p2
1  USA Hamersely M45 2023-07-22  1.75  56%
2  USA Hamersely M45 2023-07-22  1.85  76%
4  Canada Valley Y67 2023-07-22  2.37  26%
5  Canada Valley Y67 2023-07-22  1.97  86%
6  Canada Valley Y67 2023-07-22  1.75  96%
```

Comment: Works great.  I will approve this, however I'm first trying to understand it, as I will need to modify it and use it repeatedly.  Like I would like to get 'Country' and 'tournament' into their own fields as well.  Thanks